# Select has an empty value

Tags: javascript, html

I`ve a "select":

```
<select class="date-select2" name="date">
    <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
    <option value="11-2015">11-2015</option>
    <option value="10-2015">10-2015</option>
    <option value="09-2015">09-2015</option>
    <option value="07-2015">07-2015</option>
    <option value="06-2015">06-2015</option>
    <option value="04-2015">04-2015</option>
    <option value="03-2015">03-2015</option>
</select>
```

When I`m try to get value of select,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('date-select2')[0].value
```

it normally returns a value of selected item in Chrome. In FF and Safari sometimes it returns an empty string, when selected a numeric value(not "All").
How to deal with it?

Comment: What is your JavaScript code that you have tried/used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

**HTML**

```
<select class="date-select2" name="date" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
    <option value="11-2015">11-2015</option>
    <option value="10-2015">10-2015</option>
    <option value="09-2015">09-2015</option>
    <option value="07-2015">07-2015</option>
    <option value="06-2015">06-2015</option>
    <option value="04-2015">04-2015</option>
    <option value="03-2015">03-2015</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(curValue) {
    alert(curValue);
}
```

**<kbd>[Working : Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/tb3o0ryq/)</kbd>**

> **Note:** Also remember to put your JavaScript code inside `body` also right before it ends.

Comment: Thats great, but if I want to serialize form with this select? I need to make this select works in proper way

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you trying to say.

Comment: Okay, I`m understand direction to handle this

Comment: Glad that it helped you! Tested in Chrome, FF, IE, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.querySelector('select.date-select2');

// add onchange handler 
select.onchange = function(){
var idx = select.selectedIndex;

var val = select.options[idx].value;
// if All is selected use text of option
  if(val=="")
   val = select.options[idx].textContent;

};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way to get selected item:

```
$(".date-select2 option:selected").text();
```

Comment: That's jQuery, not Javascript.